# Is there any difference in using `yield self` in a method with parameter `&block` and `yield self` in a method without a parameter `&block`?

Tags: ruby, yield

I understand that

```
def a(&block)
  block.call(self)
end
```

and

```
def a()
  yield self
end
```

lead to the same result, if I assume that there is such a block `a {}`. My question is - since I stumbled over some code like that, whether it makes any difference or if there is any advantage of having (if I do not use the variable/reference block otherwise):

```
def a(&block)
  yield self
end
```

This is a concrete case where i do not understand the use of `&block`:

```
def rule(code, name, &block)
  @rules = [] if @rules.nil?
  @rules << Rule.new(code, name)
  yield self
end
```

Comment: The documentation for [Block Argument](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument) shows different use cases.

Comment: @Stefan I added a specific case where i do not understand the use of &block, maybe I miss something, so you may have a look? In addition to it I read the documentation and it corresponds to my understanding.

Comment: If you're not going to explicitly use it, don't add it to the list. It makes invocations slower and it's confusing.

Comment: @ndn "it's confusing" - Especially for a beginner. I think this lead to this question. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only advantage I can think of is for introspection:

```
def foo;       end
def bar(&blk); end

method(:foo).parameters  #=> []
method(:bar).parameters  #=> [[:block, :blk]]
```

IDEs and documentation generators could take advantage of this. However, it does not affect Ruby's argument passing. When calling a method, you can pass or omit a block, regardless of whether it is declared or invoked.

Comment: At least for me, it's not only about introspection. I find it much easier to look at the method signature and see if the last argument has a leading `&` compared to looking at the whole method and trying to find `yield` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between

```
def pass_block
  yield
end
pass_block { 'hi' } #=> 'hi'
```

and

```
def pass_proc(&blk)
  blk.call
end
pass_proc  { 'hi' } #=> 'hi'
```

is that, `blk`, an instance of `Proc`, is an object and therefore can be passed to other methods. By contrast, blocks are not objects and therefore cannot be passed around.

```
def pass_proc(&blk)
  puts "blk.is_a?(Proc)=#{blk.is_a?(Proc)}"
  receive_proc(blk)
end

def receive_proc(proc)
  proc.call
end

pass_proc { 'ho' }
blk.is_a?(Proc)=true
  #=> "ho"
```